# Going back to Russia with another passport (maybe)

Tags: visas, russia, dual-nationality

What I have:

- 1 Brazilian passport with the 90 no visa required days currently
  maxed out
- 1 European passport

  Why? I work online for myself so I can do it from anywhere and my girlfriend is currently living in Russia.

**I've been in Russia for about 90 days with a Brazilian passport** and now I want to go back before waiting 90 days.

What is the easiest passport to acquire a tourist visa with, Brazilian or European?

And if I decide to use the European should I say 'no' when they ask if I ever was in Russia?

Comment: You certainly shouldn't lie in the visa application. The question is about _you_, not about the passport you apply with. You're only one person, no matter how many different countries you're a citizen in.

Comment: AFAIK, the Russian visa system operates so that you simply cannot apply for a visa if your trip is covered with a visa-exemption agreement. You will have to invent a purpose that is not covered to get a visa into your Brazilian passport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say which European passport you have, but assuming that it is an EEA member, then it would be the easiest to use.  Overall there is not much difference between the two but the staff are likely to be more familiar with accessing the EEA system.

For your other question, you should answer 'yes' to the question if you were ever in Russia. If they find out that you have circumvented immigration controls by switching nationalities, they will be very upset. I can attest that the food in Sheremetyevo detention defines a new level of horrendous.  So it's best to play it by the book.